# Browser drag event not firing in GWT project

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

So I have 2 projects and a third party application for this situation:

app - The main app
gwt library - A library I built for re-usable GWT components
grapesjs - a drag n drop html editor in javascript

I created a gwt wrapper around the grapesjs library and in the gwt library playground, it works great. However, when I import this library into the main app, I am finding that dragging blocks onto the canvas does not work.

I dug into this as much as I could and found that the browser 'drag' event is not firing. To take this a step further, I went into the browser console on different websites and was able to attach drag listeners to any elements and they would fire properly. You can try it on stack even. Just inspect an element, alter to have `draggable="true"` and attach a listener:

```
$0.addEventListener($0, (event) => { console.log('drag event firing'); });
```

Then try to drag the element and the console logging will fire. Well, if you do the same thing in my app (any element, not just in the grapes component), it does not work. So it seems that the drag event is somehow disabled at a global level. At least, that's my best guess. My ultimate question is:

What would cause the native 'drag' event not to fire at a global level (in GWT or plain Javascript)?

I tried Chrome and FF and they both behave the same, so I don't believe it is a browser issue. I don't know what of my code would be useful for this, but I can post some stuff if asked.

Comment: I dont think this question is related to `java`. Consider removing the tag.

Comment: GWT is a Java framework and the solution may possibly be java code, so that's why I included it.

Comment: Can you share some code that shows this not working in a small GWT app? Just an entrypoint and the bit of wrapping you wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what the issue is. To answer this question generically, you can disable all manner of drag events with this in the index.html:

```
<body ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false">
</body>
```

Removing these attributes let the drag event work properly again.